# Sending sound only through HDMI (kubuntu)

Tags: sound, kubuntu, hdmi

So I am a new user to Ubuntu coming from Windows, and I wanted to connect my PC to the TV via HDMI.

I have and it works perfectly, however, I have the sound coming from both the TV and the PC and it gets annoying. I try disabling the sound on the PC, it does so on the TV as well.

It has some latency between TV and PC which makes it annoying. On Windows I'd use Win & P buttons, and the sound would be transported to the second screen along with the image.

I can transport the image only using the fn and f4 buttons (I've read this on another post) but the sound keeps coming out from both outputs. Any advice? :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a Kubuntu user too and since I connect to my TV using HDMI to watch movies I had to deal with transporting the sound from my PC to my TV only, so what I've done is this (and has worked out so I can hear sound coming from my TV only).

- Right click on the volume icon in the **System Tray**.
- Opened "**Audio Setup**" from Kmix menu.
- Clicked on the "**Audio Hardware Setup**" tab.
- Selected the best option from the **Profile** drop-down list.

In my case I selected the **Digital Stereo (HDMI) output** or the **Digital Stereo (HDMI) output + Analog Stereo Input**, clicked on **Apply** and the problem was solved.